# How to create multiple web/store in magento2?

Tags: magento2, multistore

I want to create multistore website in magento2 for this my current system configuration is as follows-

- **Web server:** Nginx
- **Magento Version:** magento2.1.0
- **Cento OS Version:** 7

for this I have followed below steps:

1. Created Website/Store/View in magento2 admin.
2. Added below code in pub/index.php

   ```
   $params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
           DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
           DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
           DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
           DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
       ];


       switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
           case 'electronics-dev.local':
           case 'www.electronics-dev.local':
               $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'electronics';
               $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
               break;
           case 'magento2-dev.local':
           case 'www.magento2-dev.local':
               $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base';
               $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
               break;
       }

       $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
       /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
       $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
       $bootstrap->run($app);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

### To create websites and stores:

- Log in to the Magento Admin as a user authorized to create websites, stores, and store views.
- Click **Stores** > **All Stores**.
- To create a website, click **Create Website**.
- To create a store, click **Create Store**.
- To create a store view, click Create Store View.
- When you create your website or store view, make note of its unique identifier because you’ll use it later.

For more information http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html